# How do I get an email bot past 2-step authentication?

Tags: python, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to set up a bot that is capable of sending emails from my outlook account. I am using python on repl.it with imapclient. I can get it to work with a standard gmail account but the problem is that my outlook account has 2-step verification and requires me to allow it on my phone, because it is a school email I cannot disable the 2 step verification. I know my username and password but cannot get the bot past 2-step. If anyone knows how to get a bot logged into the email even with 2-step enabled any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Preventing a bot from doing that is literally the point of two factor authentication. You probably could do it by setting up an insecure two factor method like SMS or another email and sending it to a client you have programmatic control over.

Comment: Unfortunately, bots CAN bypass 2fa is some way (extremely advanced which I believe only hackers do), but cannot access your email account at all. I recommend disabling 2fa as the whole point of 2fa is to prevent malicious softwares from accessing your account.

Comment: Check if there is an API that doesn't require 2fa. If there isn't, get a library that can generate these codes; probably [RFC6238](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238). Set up new 2fa on the account and store the secret in your code, with your username and password, and calculate the 2fa token as needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to bypass the bot (and assume that you cannot), use the correct authentication approach:
As with most service providers with 2FA, set up an **App Password** which allows using a different generated password for such apps.

Read [Using app passwords with apps that don't support two-step verification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944).

Another option is to provide your app with your 2FA token which you see when setting up 2FA (or set it up again). Then use an HOTP generator which will provide the correct entry code using the given token and the current time. But this is more effort than it's worth, and requires providing account details to your app which is unnecessary. Use App Passwords.